# Ocaml - Forward Declaration (Classes)

Tags: ocaml

I need to have two classes refering to each other. Is there any way in Ocaml to make Forward Declaration of one of them?

(I don't think it's possible as with easier stuff with word `and`).

Or maybe it is possible, but different way than how i tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ocaml doesn't have anything like forward declarations (i.e. a promise that something will be defined eventually), but it has recursive definitions (i.e. a block of things that are declared and then immediately defined in terms of each other). Recursive definitions are possible between expressions, types, classes, and modules (and more); mutually recursive modules allow mixed sets of objects to be defined recursively.

You can solve your problem using a recursive definition with the keyword `and`:

```
class foo(x : bar) = object
  method f () = x#h ()
  method g () = 0
end

and bar(x : foo) = object
  method h () = x#g()
end
```

Comment: @PawełMechliński: In other words: you can't write a forward declaration, but you can write a recursive definition. This is general: Ocaml doesn't have anything like forward declarations (i.e. a promise that something will be defined eventually), but it has recursive definitions (i.e. a block of things that are declared and then immediately defined in terms of each other). Recursive definitions are possible between expressions, types, classes, and modules (and more); mutually recursive modules allow mixed sets of objects to be defined recursively.

Comment: Nice explanation, Gilles. Added it to the answer and marked this Community Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use [parameterized classes](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual005.html#toc27). Following the previous example you have:

```
class ['bar] foo (x : 'bar) =
object
    method f () = x#h ()
    method g () = 0
end

class ['foo] bar (x : 'foo) =
object
    method h () = x#g()
end
```

The inferred interface is:

```
class ['a] foo : 'a ->
    object
        constraint 'a = < h : unit -> 'b; .. >
        method f : unit -> 'b
        method g : unit -> int
    end
class ['a] bar : 'a ->
    object
        constraint 'a = < g : unit -> 'b; .. >
        method h : unit -> 'b
    end
```

Comment: This answer is actually better than mine. Though you'll get far more confusing error messages if you change the name or type of h.